# How can rider move method to region?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider, region

I have multi regions in one class.
Maybe like #regionA, #regionB...
If I use auto generate method, the method will be in buttom of the class and out of any region.
Is there a way to move the method to the certain region in that class?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You could create a custom file layout ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_and_Type_Layout.html#file-and-type-layout-preferences)) and place all methods with certain properties (e. g. `private` or `static`) in a region. When applying the file layout (e. g. on commit), the code will be rearranged.

Comment: I know the custom layout, but I want to set region of usage so this doesn't work.

Comment: I think that's not possible, at least I don't know